# if statement string always prints

Tags: java

```
do{
System.out.println("Would you like to enter another number? (y/n)");
restart = console.next().charAt(0);
if (!(restart=='y')||!(restart=='n')||!(restart=='N')||!(restart=='Y'))
{
System.out.println("You entered something other than the letters (y) or (n).");
}
else if (restart=='n'||restart=='N')
   {System.out.println("Goodbye.");}
}
while (!(restart=='y')||!(restart=='n')||!(restart=='N')||!(restart=='Y'));}
            while (restart=='y'||restart=='Y');}}
```

I want the user to enter upper or lower case y or n and if its y then restart the program which worked fine before i started to add something to catch anything that wasnt a y or n. I want upper or lower case n to display goodbye and nothing happen and anything other than y or n to ask again to enter y or n until it gets the corect input and instead it always displays the you entered something other than... message and repeatedly asks if ud like to enter another number

Comment: @Braj If you count the curlies, you'll see that there's actually some additional stuff at the top, that isn't shown here.  Presumably including a `do`.

Comment: You might find `restart != 'y'` more readable than `!(restart=='y')` too.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative that you may prefer is to write

```
while("YyNn".indexOf(restart) == -1)
```

which means "loop again if `restart` is not found in `"YyNn"` ".

Answer (score 0):

Replace `||` with `&&` when you use it with `!` - otherwise you have a condition that's always true.  `restart` is ALWAYS either not Y or not N, and sometimes both.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
if (!(restart=='y')||!(restart=='n')||!(restart=='N')||!(restart=='Y'))
```

is the same as

```
if ((restart!='y')||(restart!='n')||(restart!='N')||(restart!='Y'))
```

So you probably want

```
if(!((restart=='y')||(restart=='n')||(restart=='N')||(restart=='Y')))
```

and this is the same as

```
if ((restart!='y')&&(restart!='n')&&(restart!='N')&&(restart!='Y'))
```

You can also make this if statement better by converting the value to upper or lower case letters and compare that. Then you would only have to write code for 'N' and 'Y' or 'n' and 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

You should use && instead of || in first IF and While condition check.

```
        do {
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter another number? (y/n)");

        restart = console.next().charAt(0);

        if ((restart != 'y') && (restart != 'n') && (restart != 'N') && (restart != 'Y'))
        {
            System.out.println("You entered something other than the letters (y) or (n).");
        }
        else if (restart == 'n' || restart == 'N')
        {
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        }
    }
    while ((restart != 'y') && (restart != 'n') && (restart != 'N') && (restart != 'Y'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all you do not need to create an option for capital and lowercase letters. Use .equalsIgnoreCase(). Use && instead of or because you are saying if they put yes or no it will restart.

Comment: `char` doesn't have `equalsIgnoreCase()` method.

Comment: I thought you could use .equalsIgnoreCase() on chars and strings?

Comment: this is still good advice. he should just make his char be a string and save himself from writing 1/2 the code